# Getting values from different tables in mysql query (practical example)

Tags: php, mysql

I have **two tables**: ***first*** and ***second***

*this* and *that* are primary keys, common and **always present on both tables, so I guess there is no need of left joins**

> $query = "SELECT
>   **first**.one,**first**.going,**first**.what,**first**.ever,**second**.another,**second**.outre,**second**.oneplus,**second**.more,**second**.anotherthing,**second**.alldifferent
>   WHERE **second**.THIS = **first**.THAT AND **first**.is = '1' AND
>   **first**.yet = '$variable' AND **second**.againe = '1'";

The error is the following

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE **second**.THIS = **first**.THAT AND **first**.is = '1' AND **first**.y' at line 1

But I can't get to understand why this happens.
Any help on this one? Ty very much

Comment: Syntax is as follows SELECT... FROM.. JOIN... ON... WHERE...GROUP BY...HAVING... ORDER BY... LIMIT

Comment: @Strawberry why? it worked just fine with the help from quixrick as it is.

Comment: He's just saying that you skipped the order by using your `WHERE` before you had a `FROM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a table name.

```
$query = "SELECT first.one, ... ,second.alldifferent WHERE ...";
```

Should be

```
$query = "SELECT first.one, ... ,second.alldifferent FROM first, second WHERE ...";
```

Comment: oh, nice! Which table name? The first or the second?

Comment: Both of them.  I will update my code to reflect that.